# Is there a diff tool that lets compare issues on platforms such as Jira, Gitlab etc?

Tags: timestamp, gitlab, jira, diff

I have an idea for a tool that would work as following:

You pass in the id of Jira team/Gitlab group/Whatever, and the current timestamp. The result would show the difference for every team/group member, such as whether the person has made new issues in a specified timeframe, commited new code, etc.

My question is: Is there a common tool for such purpose already existing?